# Tracking page title if it is disabled

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, matomo

The following code track the page with a specified title:

```
_paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', "<?php echo $model->id ?>"]);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

If JavaScript is disabled, how can track the page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Piwik, but it seems you should be able to still tracking using a tracking pixel using the Piwik API.

Check out the [Does Piwik track visitors without Javascript? Does Piwik track search engine bots or other spider / robots?](http://piwik.org/faq/new-to-piwik/#faq_63) FAQ.